# How to make a basic calendar with PHP?

Tags: php, loops, if-statement, calendar

I am a beginner learning PHP and I am trying to make a basic calendar with PHP. [Simpele kalender](https://www.dinkum.nl/software/web_programming/PHP_college/opdrachten/kalendertabel.php) is how it has to look. It has to be with if and/or loops. This is what I have so far:

```
<?php

$month_start = 'Tue'; 

$number_days = 28; 

// number of rows
$number_rows = $number_days / 7;
    if ($number_days % 7 != 0) {
// number of days
$number_rows = ($number_days / 7) + 1;
}
?>

<table>
<tr>
<th>Mon</th>
<th>Tue</th>
<th>Wed</th>
<th>Thu</th>
<th>Fri</th>
<th>Sat</th>
<th>Sun</th>
</tr>

<?php
for($y = 1; $y <= $number_rows;$y++){
echo "<tr>";
for($i = 1; $i <= $number_days; $i++){
    if($i % 7 != 0){
      echo "<td>". $i . "</td>";
    }
    else{
      echo "<td>". $i . "</td>";
      break;

    }


}
echo "</tr>";
}
?>
</table>
<style>
  table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}
</style>
```

How do I start on Thursday (beginning of the month) and how can I get the days 1 to 28 in the columns? I made another calendar but that wasn't correct. According to the feedback I got on it, I don't need to use gmdate, cal_days_in_month and mktime. Anyone that can help me go into the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

One option is to give the days of the week numbers: Mon=0, Tues=1, etc. You can set a variable `$start_day = 3;` where 3 is for Thursday. Then add that to get the total number of rows: `$number_rows = ceil(($start_day + $number_days) / 7);` Lastly, create a variable to mark the current day number to be printed. Initialize it to `-$start_day` and only print if not negative:

```
$number_days = 28; 
$start_day = 3; // Mon=0, Tues=1, etc

// Add in $start_day her to account for the "negative" days before the 1st day
$number_rows = ceil(($start_day + $number_days) / 7);

$current_day = -$start_day;

for ($row = 0; $row < $number_rows; $row++) {
    echo("<tr>");
    for ($col = 0; $col < 7; $col++) {
        echo("<td>");
        // Only print the day number if it is not a "negative" day and is not past the end
        if ($current_day++ >= 0 && $current_day <= $number_days) {
            echo($current_day);
        }
        echo("</td>");
    }
    echo("</tr>");
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can use **if($loopCount++ > number)** to start DAY inside LOOP

***This is an example***

```
$count = 1;
foreach($colum as $res)
    {
    echo'<td>';
    
    if($count++ > 3){echo $days++;} //will start in the third loop
    
    echo'</td>';
    }
```

***Apply Like This***

```
<?php
//TOTAL DAY ON THIS MONTH
$total_days = 30;
//WHERE DAY START
$start_days = 3;
//TOTAL COLUM OF CALENDAR
$col = 27;  //27 because this will be an array, because the array has 0 so the total will be 28
for($x = 0; $x <= $col; $x++) 
    {
    $colum[] = $x;
    }

echo "<table><tr>";
$days = 1;
$count = 1; 
foreach($colum as $res)
    {

    echo'<td>';if($count++ > $start_days){echo $days++;} echo'</td>';

    if ($count++ % 7 == 0) 
        {
        echo "</tr><tr>";
        } 
    }
//NEX MONTH START WITH THIS
$rest_of_the_day = $total_days - $days + 1;

echo"</tr></table>";
```

Comment: Does this answer OPs question or did you just optimize their code? Also please reformat your code with a proper indentation.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I created a calendar. This creates "non-days" i.e. greyed-out (you'll have to style yourself) squares so that the first day of the month will start on its proper weekday place.

```php
    $year = 2022;
    $date = new DateTime("".$year."-01-01");
    $weekday = (int)$date->format('N');
    $weekn = (int)$date->format('W');
    $day = 1;
    $month = 1;
    $dayLabels = array("Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun");

    // This creates a "table head" for each month
    $thead = '<tr><th>M</th><th>W</th>';
    foreach($dayLabels as $lbl) $thead .= "<th>".$lbl."</th>";
    $thead .= '</tr>';
    
    // This variable will hold the html table of the calendar
    $calendar = '<table id="calendar" border="1" style="width: 550px; max-width: 100%;">';

    // Loop each month until 12
    for(;$month <= 12; $month++)
    {
        $calendar .= $thead;
        $monthday = 1;
        $monthmax = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $month, $year);
        $position = 0;
  
        while($monthday <= $monthmax)
        {
            // Create month and week columns
            if($position == 0)
            {
                $weekn = (int)$date->format('W');
                $calendar .= "<tr><th>".$month."</th><th>".$weekn."</th>";
                $position++;
            } // Create "non-days"
            else if($position < $weekday)
            {
                $calendar .= "<td class=\"nonday\"></td>";
                $position++;
            } // Create days
            else if($position == $weekday)
            {
                $calendar .= "<td class=\"day\">".$monthday."</td>";
                $position++;
                $weekday++;
                $monthday++;
                $date->modify('+1 day');
                
                if($position == 8)
                {
                    $position = 0;
                    $weekday = 1;
                }
            }
        }
        
        // Finish "non-days"
        while($position != 0)
        {
            $calendar .= "<td class=\"nonday\"></td>";
            $position++;
            if($position == 8) $position = 0;
        }
        $calendar .= "</tr>";
        if($month != 12) $calendar .= '<td colspan="9" class="monthlinebreak"></td>';
    }

    return $calendar;
```